# Google OAuth, Refresh token invalid

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth

I am using the [Google PHP SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to connect to Google My Business and get an access token.

After connection with Google (Client), everything works, but when around 1-2 days pass, I start to get "Bad Request" and error code "invalid_grant" from
[here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Client.php#L334).

Meaning that the refresh token is not valid anymore. Then I have to disconnect the google connection and re-connect to make it work for 1-2 days.

I am also [setting the refresh token for offline use](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline). Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are serval reasons why a refresh token can [expire](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
- The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has session control policies in effect.

Currently the most common one is

A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

The first thing you should check is that your application is set to production and not testing in the consent screen.